# Cast to type which is not inherited

Tags: java, reflection, casting

I have class lets say

```
public class Magic implements Serializable{
}
```

and this class does not inherit

```
public class Amount{
}
```

Is there any way to cast `Magic` to `Amount`, I will be not accessing any fields what so ever, i just need Magic to "become" Amount? Is there any way?

Comment: Why would you even need to do that?

Comment: No. trying to do so will end up in an ClassCastException at runtime. Why would you want to do that? Maybe there is another solution for your underlaying business problem...

Comment: If they have nothing to do with each other, why do you want to do it?

Comment: Because i have a method which requires to be put "Amount" however i cannot make Magic extends Amount(another jar in which i cannot write to), and i need a way somehow Magic to become Amount, i can't modify the both files.

Comment: Then why don't you use `(Amount) null`? You said you won't be touching any of Amount's members. So null is just as good as a Magic instance.

Comment: While C# provides some syntactic sugar to convert between objects of different classes using cast-like notation. Java, for better or worse, does not.

Comment: As everyone has said, no you cannot cast `Magic` to `Account`. Maybe the State pattern https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern is what you need for whatever you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @MichaelJapesonYou've just learned why "composition over inheritance" is a thing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casting does not automatically convert objects from one type to another type.

A cast is a way to disable the compiler's type checks. The only thing that a cast does, is tell the compiler: "Here is an object, and I know better than you what kind of object this is, so I want you to treat it as an object of this type, and not complain".

A type check will still be done, at runtime, and if at that time the object really is not of the type that you said it was, you will get a `ClassCastException`.

A cast cannot automatically convert a `Magic` object into an `Amount` object.

You need to write the code yourself to create an `Amount` object using the data of the `Magic` object.

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't. An instance of `Amount` is *unrelated* to an instance of `Magic`.

This is true even if the two classes *look* identical, which in your case they certainly are not.

In this case, you need to suffer the pain of writing the code to convert `Magic` to an `Amount`. Perhaps have a constructor in `Amount` that takes a `Magic` instance as the parameter.

Alternatively, if `Amount` contains only functions, then consider recasting it as an `interface`, which is implemented by `Magic`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast between unrelated types in Java. If you need to create an `Amount` instance from a `Magic` instance you should have a constructor that receives such an argument:

```
public class Amount {
    public Amount(Magic m) {
        // Initialize amount's fields...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to have `Magic` become `Amount` is to have your class: `Magic` extend the `Amount` class.

You want an `is a` link between classes and this is done by inheritance.

Otherwise you will receive a compilation error.